# Couldn't match expected type `IO b0' with actual type `[a0]'

Tags: haskell, greatest-common-divisor

I'm new to haskell guys. I'm trying to write a gcd executable file.

```
ghc --make gcd
```

When I compile this code I'm getting the following error.

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO b0' with actual type `[a0]' 
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  putStrLn "GCD is: " ++ gcd' num1 num2 ++ "TADA...."
In the expression:
  do { putStrLn "Hello,World. This is coming from Haskell";
       putStrLn "This is the GCD";
       putStrLn "Frist Number";
       input <- getLine;
       .... }
In an equation for `main':
    main
      = do { putStrLn "Hello,World. This is coming from Haskell";
             putStrLn "This is the GCD";
             putStrLn "Frist Number";
             .... }
```

I don't understand where my problem is... Here is my code.

```
gcd' :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> a
gcd' x y = gcd' (abs x) (abs y)
      where gcd' a 0  =  a
        gcd' a b  =  gcd' b (a `rem` b)

main = do
    putStrLn "Hello,World. This is coming from Haskell"
    putStrLn "This is the GCD"
    putStrLn "Frist Number"
    input <- getLine
    let num1 = (read input)
    putStrLn "Second Number"
    input2 <- getLine
    let num2 = read input2
    putStrLn "GCD is: " ++ gcd' num1 num2 ++ "TADA...."
```

All I know is that `read` helps me convert my string into an int.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you need parentheses,

```
putStrLn ("GCD is: " ++ gcd' num1 num2 ++ "TADA....")
```

or infix function application `($)`:

```
putStrLn $ "GCD is: " ++ gcd' num1 num2 ++ "TADA...."
```

Without that, the line is parsed as

```
(putStrLn "GCD is: ") ++ gcd' num1 num2 ++ "TADA...."
```

and the concatenation of the IO-action `putStrLn "GCD is: "` with a `String` is what causes the - somewhat cryptic, before one has enough experience - type error.

From the context in that the line appears - in an `IO`-do-block - it must have type `IO b` for some `b`. But the type inferred from the application of `(++)` is `[a]` for some type `a`. These types cannot be matched, and that's what the compiler reports.

Note that after fixing that, you also need to convert the result of `gcd'` to a `String`,

```
putStrLn $ "GCD is: " ++ show (gcd' num1 num2) ++ "TADA...."
```

or you'll see another type error.

---

From the comment

> To make my program look nicer. Is there a way that the input area is right next to the statement instead of a line down?

In general, yes. Instead of using `putStrLn` which appends a newline to the output string, use `putStr` which doesn't.

```
putStr "Second Number: "
input2 <- getLine
```

In interactive mode (ghci), that works well. `stdout` is not buffered there. For compiled programmes, `stdout` is usually line-buffered, that means it will not output anything until a newline shall be output or the buffer is full.

So for a compiled programme, you need to explicitly flush the output buffer,

```
import System.IO -- for hFlush

putStr "Second Number: "
hFlush stdout
input2 <- getLine
```

or turn off buffering altogether

```
import System.IO

main = do
    hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
    ...
```

But at least the latter method used to not work on Windows (I'm not sure whether that's fixed, nor am I absolutely sure that `hFlush`ing works on Windows).

Comment: To make my program look nicer. Is there a way that the input area is right next to the statement instead of a line down?

Comment: Sure (generally), I'll add it to the answer, since there is a point about buffering that might not fit in a comment.

Comment: Aww...man...hFlush stdout isn't working for me. It's still printing out on the next line.

Comment: Using `putStr` instead of `putStrLn`? What exactly is happening, which GHC version, which platform?

Comment: Yes it works !! xD thanks I didn't catch that hahaha Works Beautifully

Comment: This may be a question out of the ordinary... but for my gcd method. How do I figure out the time complexity of it since it uses recursion so many times?

Comment: If you just want the result: That calculates the gcd in O(log (min{|x|, |y|}+1) + 1) steps (`+1` to avoid the `log 0` problem, and deal with the one step for a 0 input). If you want to know how to calculate it, that's far longer to explain than fits here. Maybe [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) explains it. It's explained in TAOCP, you can deduce it from the continued fraction algorithm, ...

Comment: Cool! I've been also trying to figured it's probably better to make a batch executable instead of having to compile every single time, but is that even possible for haskell? My friend told me he did it through xp, but since I'm running on a mac environment is it any different?

Comment: What do you mean "compile every single time"? You compile once and you get a binary that you can run whenever you want. The code above prompts for the input, but you could also pass arguments on the command line and get them via `System.Environment.getArgs`. If you mean running the code without compiling, 1. there's ghci (`i` as in interactive), 2. runhaskell (run a programme with a `main` without compiling, well, interpreted, byte code).

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to do is make an executable on mac so I can double click it and it will compile it and run the code lol.